# Woocommerce custom attributes list help

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I have a single product page in Woocommerce and on the right, I have a box for different sizes. my current HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default dimensions">
                          <div class="panel-heading">Available size(s)</div>
                          <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">size1</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">size2</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">size3</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">size4</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">size5</li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
```

which shows the sizes how i want it but I want to add my custom Woocommerce product attribute in there using the same style, does anyone have any ideas how this is done?

My product attribute is set to:

Product Sizes:

size1
size2
size3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
<?php
global $product;
$sizes = $product->get_attribute( 'size' ); $sizes = explode(", ",$sizes); ?>
<?php if($sizes[0]!=''){ // if product sizes are defined ?>
   <ul class="list-group">
    <?php foreach($sizes as $size){ ?>
      <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $size; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it seems to break the site, typo maybe somewhere? I changed the ('size') to my version which is ('product_size')

Comment: Corrected, i forgot the semi-colon after `$product`

Comment: that fixed the issue but it's loading them all in one list-group-item, in the custom attribute i have put them all in but in a different line, could that be an issue?

Comment: I changed the attribute from the product page to the actual attribute page on the products drop down, does this change the way the code is inputted

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly.